# How to add multiple individual in civicrm profile fields section in civicrm contribution page?

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, profile

I need to create a Household with Individual Members in a Contribution Page.

So an Individual will have
**First Name, Last Name and Email Id**

&
Household will have
**Household Name**
I need to add this in a profile and when a user adds the above, it will create a Household with individual members (multiple) listed in a profile.
How can I add fields such that we have an option to add multiple individual members by clicking on **Add More button** which will place the First Name, Last Name and Email Id fields?

Comment: not directly answering key issue but I feel like there would not be a lot of work involved in making the 'on behalf of' be extended to work with Households, which would at least do the joining of the first human to the Household

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this cannot be achieved with CiviCRM profiles.
CiviCRM only offers an option to sign up as an individual or on behalf of an organisation.
A household cannot be linked via a contribution page.

You best option with WordPress would be to attempt building a form using CiviCRM caldera forms - https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm